# Deserializing JToken result using JSON.net

Tags: c#, json.net

Using Newtonsoft JSON.net, I have the following JToken result:

```
"60": {
  "maps": false,
  "real_time": false,
  "video_pack_results": {},
  "indented": 0,
  "blog_posts": false,
  "description": "A LONDON household is celebrating a U-turn by an insurance company that   means the occupants no longer have to foot half a pounds 25000 bill for ...",
  "base_url": "www.independent.co.uk",
  "place_pack": {},
  "dirty_url": "/url?q=http://www.independent.co.uk/news/business/subsidence-leads-to-an-insurance-fallout-transfer-of-property-freehold-leaves-flat-owners-without-full-cover-1481999.html&sa=U&ei=qiPFUIv2J4WJiwLc3ICQAQ&ved=0CKMBEBYwJzgU&usg=AFQjCNFbJ0NSAqXOnBdAViKZXQidPK1vEg",
  "video": false,
  "href": "http://www.independent.co.uk/news/business/subsidence-leads-to-an-insurance-fallout-transfer-of-property-freehold-leaves-flat-owners-without-full-cover-1481999.html",
  "title": "Subsidence leads to an insurance fall-out: Transfer of property ...",
  "news": false,
  "shopping": false,
  "micro_format": false,
  "image": false,
  "place_details": {},
  "image_pack_results": [],
  "url": "http://www.independent.co.uk/news/business/subsidence-leads-to-an-insurance-fallout-transfer-of-property-freehold-leaves-flat-owners-without-full-cover-1481999.html",
  "brand_pack_results": {},
  "local_pack": {},
  "page": 7,
  "base_domain": "independent.co.uk"
}
```

Which I'm trying to retrieve the value "60" from when parsing out from JSON.net using the following method:

```
var keyValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(jToken.ToString());
```

The first error I encountered was missing "{" "}" tags surrounding the initial content which I initially appended to the raw JSON string from the JToken. The result of this was an empty KeyValuePair type.

Does anyone know a way in which to parse a JToken in the format above in order to separate out the Key and Value properties?

Answer (score 1):

1. `jToken.First` will remove the `"60": {` leaving you with only keyvalue pairs.
2. Use `IDictionary` instead of `KeyValuePair<string, string>>` on `jToken.First.ToString()` which will solve your problem.

Let me know if this works